# Uniform inequality for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x,y)\in \mathcal{C}([a,b]\times[c,d])$ such that $$\exists \xi\in (a,b) : f(\xi,y)\neq 0, \forall y\in [c,d].$$

By the continuity of $f$, we have
$$|f(\xi,\cdot)|\geq \min\limits_{[c,d]} |f(\xi,\cdot)|=\alpha_0>0. \;(1)$$

I want to know if we can prove the following result:

There exists an open interval $I\subset [a,b]$ and $C>0$ such that
$$\forall (x,y)\in I\times [c,d]: |f(x,y)|\geq C>0, \; (2).$$
If we use continuity of $f(\cdot,y)$ for each $y\in [c,d]$, by $(1)$ there exists an open interval $I_y$ containing $\xi$ such that
$$\forall y\in [c,d], \forall x\in I_y: |f(x,y)|\geq \alpha_0>0.$$
But this is not what I'm looking for. I need two independent intervals such that $(2)$ holds.

If this is not true in general, can someone give a counter-example ?

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks for the "down vote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $|f|\geq \alpha_0$ on $\{\xi\}\times [c,d].$ By the uniform continuity of $|f|$ on $[a,b]\times [c,d],$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|p-q|<\delta$ implies $| \,|f(p)|-|f(q)|\,|<\alpha_0/2.$ Thus $|\,|f(x,y)|-|f(\xi,y)|\,| < \alpha_0/2$ if $x\in (\xi-\delta, \xi+ \delta).$ It follows that $|f| > \alpha_0/2$ on $(\xi-\delta, \xi+ \delta)\times [c,d].$

Comment: Thank you, I said "uniform inequality" but didn't try to use uniform continuity.

Comment: we can always choose $\delta$ such that $\delta <\min(b-\xi,\xi)$ to ensure that we still in $[a,b]$, right ?

Comment: Sure. I was thinking of  $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ as my metric space.